# Unable to run Jest Snapshot tests with jest-puppeteer

Tags: jestjs, next.js, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I just added jest-puppeteer to include it in my testing suites. Part of the setup is to remove `testEnvironment:"jsdom"` in my `jest.config.js` according to https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer. Considering I'm using Next.js which may be running on the server and doesn't have access to browser objects such as document, How do I run my snapshot tests without `testEnvironment:"jsdom"`? I was looking for a way to change jest configuration programmatically but I couldn't find any. Is there an approach to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

same case here.

You can do the following:

1. Create two separated configs for the unit and for the integration testing.
2. Name your unit and integration tests with different suffixes: .unit.js || .int.js
3. Create different commands in the package.json

jest.config.unit.js:

```
{testEnvironment: 'jsdom', testRegex: "\\.unit\\.ts"}
```

jest.config.integration.js:

```
{preset: "jest-puppeteer", testRegex: "\\.int\\.ts"}
```

package.json:

```
"unit": "jest -c jest.config.unit.js",
"int": "jest -c jest.config.integration.js",
```

And in the test folder:

/unit/test.unit.js

/int/test.int.js